# Derivative of sum of two exponential functions

Tags: derivatives

I have the following formula -

$$ f(x) = \left(0.1 e^{-1.5{x}^{0.2}} + 0.9 e^{-0.5{x}^{0.1}}\right)^{c}$$

where $\bf c$ is a constant value. How can I solve $f'(x)$ ?

According to the answer, I have got:

$$ f'(x) = c \left(0.1 e^{-1.5{x}^{0.2}} + 0.9 e^{-0.5{x}^{0.1}}\right) ^{c-1} (-0.03 e^{-1.5{x}^{0.2}} - 0.045 e^{-0.5{x}^{0.1}})$$

Is my answer right?

Comment: Seems like you have missed something. Can you show your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to differentiate this formula, you need to be familiar with the chain rule. It says that: $$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

Hence, the derivative of your formula becomes:

$$c\cdot (0.1e^{-1.5x^{0.2}}+0.5e^{-0.5x^{0.1}})^{c-1}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(0.1e^{-1.5x^{0.2}}+0.5e^{-0.5x^{0.1}})$$

In the second part of the derivative, you need to apply the chain rule again. The solution becomes:

$c\cdot (0.1e^{-1.5x^{0.2}}+0.5e^{-0.5x^{0.1}})^{c-1}\cdot(-\frac{0.045e^{-0.5x^{0.1}}}{x^{0.9}}-\frac{0.03e^{-1.5x^{0.2}}}{x^{0.8}})$.

Comment: Recheck your method. It should be -0.045 instead of -0.025 .

Comment: I corrected my mistake. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

$[g(x)^c]' = c\cdot g(x)^{c-1}g'(x)$

I assume you can differentiate the term in the brackets (the $g(x)$).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, you have to use **chain rule** here. It is : $$\frac{d}{dx} \left(f(g(x)\right) = f'(g(x)) g'(x) -----\text{equation (1)} $$
The given expression $$ f(x) = \left( 0.1 e^{-1.5x^{0.2}} + 0.9 e^{-0.5 x^{0.1}} \right)^c $$ is quite similar to the equation (1) mentioned above.

In order to find $f'(x)$ , let us first make it a little bit simpler.

$$f(x) = \left(g(x)\right)^c \quad ; \text{where} \space g(x) = 0.1e^{-1.5x^{0.2}} + 0.9 e^{-0.5x^{0.1}} $$

Now, according to the chain rule :  $$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = c \times g'(x) \times g(x)^{c-1} $$

Now, you have to find $g'(x)$ as the other two terms will remain as it is. We don't need to touch them. To solve for $g'(x)$ , you will need to a little bit of work here. Remember that : $$\frac{d(a \times f(x) )}{dx} = a \frac{df(x)}{dx} $$ where a is a constant.

Good Luck with your problem. Let me know if you get any problems while working on it.